# Sending mail via PHP - Mac OS X and postfix problem

Tags: macos, postfix-mta

I have MAMP installed on my Mac OS X 10.6 install and I'm trying to send email, via PHP, but it doesn't seem to like the fact that postfix isn't installed:

`Apr 18 12:27:36 billy-pc postfix[7959]: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command
Apr 18 12:27:36 billy-pc postfix[7959]: fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser`

I have a folder in `/etc/postfix` but for some reason postfix doesn't want to start or send mail

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seemed to have fixed my problem. I'm not 100% sure why, I simply stopped and started postfix and sent a test using:

`printf "Subject: TestnHello" | sendmail -f myemail@gmail.com anotheremail@gmail.com`

This seemed to send and I can now send mail via PHP. Strange